# OSM Overpass API: Complete boundary data

Tags: openstreetmap, overpass-api

I am trying to figure out if it is possible with the OverpassAPI to download all boundary data for a country.

Small example: Luxembourg
I would like to get all relations that are tagged as (key-value) boundary=administrative. I would like to receive all ways to these relations, and all nodes in these ways.

I assume that could be quite a lot of data (?) so I wonder if one query is the way to go, especially if I would try to do it with Germany or France (with about 20 items on admin_level=4, and hundreds on admin_level=6 or 8)

This is further complicated because the bounding box around the country takes in all other countries sharing a border with the one "in-box".

So this seems not to be the way - what technique would I use to get all nodes on all ways that form administrative boundaries of a country?

What I am currently trying is this

```
<osm-script>
  <query type="relation">
    <bbox-query s="49" w="2" n="52" e="7"/>
    <has-kv k="boundary" v="administrative"/>
    <has-kv k="admin_level" v="2"/>
  </query>
  <print mode="meta"/>
</osm-script>
```

This is a bounding box for Belgium (say mid-size), and restricted to admin_level=2. Also, this does not yet deliver node information.

I know how to change that - but this will deliver all neighbouring countries too. What is a better way of doing this?

Thanks!
Ralf

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend to look at OSM Boundaries map instead, a dedicated application for worldwide boundary on just about any level you can think of:  https://wambachers-osm.website/boundaries

In any case, there's quite some load on the main overpass api instance and it is likely that you will hit a HTTP 429 error when running the following query to fetch all ways and nodes for Germany:

`(rel(51477);>;);out meta;`

or:

`(rel[boundary=administrative][admin_level=2][name="Deutschland"];>;);out meta;`

To get all boundary=administrative relations with all of their ways and nodes in Luxemburg, the following query should do (careful: returns 47 MB of data, including Germany, Rhineland-Palatine and Saarland).

`rel(2171347);
map_to_area;
(rel[boundary=administrative](area);>;);
out meta;`

Maybe try [this alternative](http://www.openstreetmap.org/user/mmd/diary/39568) as well.